# Inline diff view in revision history breaks runnable code snippets

Tags: bug, revisions-list, stack-snippets

When viewing the inline diff view in the revision history of a post, pressing the "Run code snippet" button tries to concatenate both revisions:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why would you try to run an inline diff file?

Comment: Because I can. I'm a simple user, I see a clickable button, I click.

Comment: What would you expect to happen? Should the button not be shown? Should it pop up a warning? Should it run the correctly "merged" code? Something else?

Comment: @wimi The fact that the button even shows up can be considered the bug that is being reported here. The best way to fix it is just to hide it.

Comment: @rene See above; IMO the best way to fix this is just to not show the button.

Comment: @rene Correctly "merged" code, for the revision the button belongs to